# Android SQLite Database Use

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have found numerous web references on how to use a SQLite database.

But everything I have found has the DatabaseHelper - **onCreate()** routine creating a Data Table.

I want to create an Empty SQLite Database (No Tables) and then add tables later on an as-need basis.

1. Is it REQUIRED that 1 data table be added in order to Create a Database?
2. When I have tried to utilize the **openOrCreateDatabase()** function in my DatabaseHelper class, it comes up as un-resolved.

Your advice/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it REQUIRED that 1 data table be added in order to Create a Database?

You should be able to have a `SQLiteOpenHelper` that does nothing in `onCreate()`.

Or, use `openOrCreateDatabase()` on `SQLiteDatabase`.

> When I have tried to utilize the openOrCreateDatabase() function in my DatabaseHelper class, it comes up as un-resolved.

That is a static method on `SQLiteDatabase`, not `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Answer (score 0):

What you suggest is doable, but I don't get the point of not initialising your database with the default system.

In any case, keep in mind:

1. The `onCreate` method is not called until you don't get an instance of `SQLiteDatabase` from your `SQLiteOpenHelper`.
2. You can always create new tables or execute any kind of query in your database using [`SQLiteDatabase#exeSQL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

So to your question:

> Is it REQUIRED that 1 data table be added in order to Create a
>   Database

No, your database will be created the first time you get a reference to a SQLiteDatabase, for example calling to `getWritableDatabase`.

> When I have tried to utilize the openOrCreateDatabase() function in my
>   DatabaseHelper class, it comes up as un-resolved.

This method is more for internal use from the context. Use the open helper which is the preferred and recommended method.